# Cannot insert into tables referencing each other (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a problems inserting into a table that has a circular relationship with another table. In the schema below, each table has a foreign key that references the other:

```
create table SUPPLIERS (
    SName varchar(60) primary key, 
    SAddress varchar(60) not null,
    PCategory varchar(60) unique references PRODUCTS deferrable initially deferred
);

create table PRODUCTS (
    Prodname varchar(60) primary key,  
    SName varchar(60) unique references SUPPLIERS deferrable initially deferred,
    PCategory varchar(60) not null,
    Price real not null
);
```

Now, when I execute these statements:

```
insert into SUPPLIERS values
    ('Babolat', 'Topanga', 'Sports'),
    ('Infusium', 'Los Angeles', 'Beauty'),
    ('Market Pantry', 'San Jose', 'Food'),
    ('Staples', 'Burbank', 'Office')
;
insert into PRODUCTS values
    ('Tennis racket', 'Babolat', 'Sports', 100),
    ('Shampoo', 'Infusium', 'Beauty', 10),
    ('Water', 'Market Pantry', 'Food', 3),
    ('Paper', 'Staples', 'Office', 20)
;
```

the following error is thrown:

```
ERROR:  relation "products" does not exist

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "products" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

I attempted to use the `deferred` keyword to perhaps get the server to perform the insert and do the foreign key check **after** the transaction is done, but it still throws the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do all your supplier have to have a product in the first place?

Comment: The error message "relation does not exist" is pretty clear. Maybe you created the tables using double quotes around the name? `"PRODUCTS"` is a different table name then `PRODUCTS`. [See the manual for details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). If this is the case the deferrable won't help you at all. But this design doesn't really make sense to me in the first place. Shouldn't you have a category table that is referenced from suppliers and products?

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
ALTER TABLE SUPPLIERS DROP CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERS_fkey;

insert into SUPPLIERS values
('Babolat', 'Topanga', 'Sports'),
('Infusium', 'Los Angeles', 'Beauty'),
('Market Pantry', 'San Jose', 'Food'),
('Staples', 'Burbank', 'Office');


insert into PRODUCTS values
('Tennis racket', 'Babolat', 'Sports', 100),
('Shampoo', 'Infusium', 'Beauty', 10),
('Water', 'Market Pantry', 'Food', 3),
('Paper', 'Staples', 'Office', 20);

ALTER TABLE SUPPLIERS
 ADD CONSTRAINT SUPPLIERS_fkey FOREIGN KEY (PCategory)
  REFERENCES products (PCategory) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```